# Unable to login with my Stack Exchange account to Stack Overflow from an iPad (Safari)

Tags: support, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

For some reasons, I am unable to login to Stack Overflow from Safari on my iPad, whereas it works fine from my Chrome app.

I have this issue only since yesterday. Before that I used to login from my Safari app only, and I had no issues. Does anyone else face this issue?

When I click login, and then the Stack Exchange icon, the JavaScript doesn't work as expected.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details? What exactly are you doing that is not working? What do you mean by "the JavaScript doesn't work as expected"? What do you expect and how do you know it isn't working that way?

Comment: @Oded after tapping the StackExchange icon in the login options.. it is supposed to take me to open id screen.. but it do nothing. I am not able to login at all.. I have been using for 2 months.. only today. i have this issue.

Comment: Is this here on Meta or other sites? Are you seeing any JavaScript errors in the console (and if so, what are they)?

Comment: I dont have the console or other developer tools available in iPad's safari version. (atleast I dont know how to see it) stackoverflow and meta.stackoverflow.. both dont work for me.. whereas.. stackexchange.com works fine.

Comment: Strange, as Meta currently has a different log in page than [so] does. Both are not working for you? Do the top bar drop downs work?

Comment: Yes, it works well.. am able to switch pages from meta SO to the SO

Comment: I even tried restarting my device.. cleared cookies.. so this should be some recent JS change at serverside. made it incompatible.

Comment: Possibly. Though without developer tools or JavaScript errors, I can't tell. I don't have an iPad to test with (and this is the weekend, after all), so will see if someone in the team can reproduce soon.

Comment: And i should admit... I am not happy with this.. working with chrome is a workaround.. but the navigation is not okay.. Also SQLFIDDLE.COM even doesnt work with ipad safari.. in chrome it works.

Comment: @Oded No need, it's just the great private browsing bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on an iPad, and I can see that you have private browsing enabled. Disable private browsing and it should work fine.

Comment: Wow.. Yes you were right! It was in Private.. I wonder did I ever turn it ON. SQL fiddle too works fine.. But it had been in private quite a while.. Now. i realised... I had logged out yesterday.. after a month.. as i never log out in my device.. and my next login got problematic(some bug) since I was in private browsing...